# How can i have a discord.py grab someones text and run it through a piece of code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a feature that lets bot say "Rhyme: " when someone does $rhyme. I have the rhyme feature down on python but don't know how to implement it to Discord.py. The thing i need to know is how to grab someones text and assign it to a variable.
All the things i searched up dont have the discord.py setup like mine, I will send the important pieces of code that are relevant

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

async def rhyme(message):
    await message.channel.send("Rhyme: ")
    pass

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$rhyme'):
        rhyme()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're trying to make a command that will be executed as such:

```
$rhyme [some word]
```

This means you're trying to retrieve the argument that was passed in with the command. To do this, the best way is to make commands, instead of using only events and such. Here is a piece of code to demonstrate what to do:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands  # This will be important

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')  # This instantiates the client, and the prefix

@client.command()
async def rhyme(ctx, word):  # The word will be the 'variable' you should be looking for
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
    rhyming_word = rhyme(word)  # Here, you would put the function that will get the rhyming word or whatever you're looking for
    await ctx.send(f'Rhyme: {rhyming_word}')  # Send out the word that you got from the function above
```

In the code above, I'm assuming that the word that the user inputs to `rhyme` will be taken into the command, and then you will send back a word that rhymes with that word. But for the code above to work, you need to have the `rhyme()` function look a little something like this:

```py
def rhyme(word):
    if word == 'cat':
        return 'hat'
    if word == 'hi':
        return 'bye'
```

In the end, you need the `rhyme()` function to take in the word that you want, and return the word that rhymes with the word that was taken in. For example, `cat` and `hat`, or `hi` and `bye`.

Answer (score 1):

`discord.Message` has the attribute `content`

```py
if message.content.starswith("$rhyme"):
    await rhyme(message) # It's a coroutine so you need to await it
```

The rhyme function:

```py
async def rhyme(message):
    content = message.content # This is the content of the message, e.g `$rhyme hello there`
    await message.channel.send(f"Rhyme: {content}")
```

I'm pretty sure that you copied the code from somewhere as you used `message.content` in the `on_message` event, next time read the docs

#### Reference:

- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20content#discord.Message.content)